# How to add Undo Button Functionality?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

[image]

This is my Roulette Game Project and I am new learner in Unity. In this project, I am facing an issue with creating an undo button.

This is my code for the undo button:

```cs
public void Undo() {
    if (Bets.Count != 0 && BetSpaces.Count != 0) {
        var lastBet = Bets.Last();
        var lastSpace = BetSpaces.Last();
        //UserDetail.Balance += lastBet.chip;
        UserDetail.Balance += BetSpaces.Last().stack.value;
        UpdateBalance(UserDetail.Balance);
        lastSpace.SetAllMeshes(false);
        lastSpace.Clear();
        Bets.Remove(lastBet);
        BetSpaces.Remove(lastSpace);
        var totalBets = int.Parse(TotalBetCount.text);
        if (totalBets > 0) TotalBetCount.text = (totalBets--).ToString();
        TakeButton.interactable = false;
    }
    var indexesToRemove = new List<int>();
    BetSpaces.ForEach(X => {
        GlobalFunctions.PrintLog($"X: {X.stack.value}");
        if (X.stack.value == 0) {
            indexesToRemove.Add(BetSpaces.IndexOf(X));
        } else {
            X.SetAllMeshes(true);
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < indexesToRemove.Count; i++) {
        Bets.RemoveAt(indexesToRemove[i]);
        BetSpaces.RemoveAt(indexesToRemove[i]);
    }
    UndoButton.interactable = Bets.Count != 0;
    SceneRoulette._Instance.clearButton.interactable = Bets.Count != 0;
    SceneRoulette._Instance.rollButton.interactable = Bets.Count != 0;
}
```

Here's a breakdown of how the function works:

Condition Checking:

--> It first checks if there are any bets made (Bets.Count != 0).

--> If there are no bets made, it essentially means there's nothing to undo, so the function returns without performing any further actions.

Undoing the Last Bet:

--> If there are bets made, it retrieves the details of the last bet placed (lastBet) and the corresponding betting space (lastSpace).

--> It then adds back the betting amount to the player's balance (UserDetail.Balance += BetSpaces.Last().stack.value), effectively refunding the player for the undone bet.

--> It clears the visuals associated with the last betting space (lastSpace.SetAllMeshes(false)), removing any visual indication of the bet on the game interface.

--> It removes the last bet (Bets.Remove(lastBet)) and the corresponding betting space (BetSpaces.Remove(lastSpace)) from their respective lists.

--> It updates the total bet count displayed on the UI, reducing it by the amount of the undone bet if the total bet count is greater than 0.

Handling Remaining Bets:

--> It then iterates over all the betting spaces to check if any of them have a stack value of 0, indicating that no bets have been placed on them.

--> If a betting space has a stack value of 0, it removes both the bet and the betting space from their respective lists.

--> This step ensures that any empty betting spaces (where the player has placed no bets) are removed from consideration, keeping the bet and betting space lists synchronized.

Updating Button Interactivity:

--> Finally, it updates the interactivity of various buttons on the game interface based on the presence of remaining bets.

--> If there are remaining bets (Bets.Count != 0), it enables the clear and roll buttons while disabling the undo button.

--> If there are no remaining bets, it disables all buttons since there's nothing left to do.

Overall, the Undo() function provides a mechanism for players to retract their last betting actions, returning their wagered amount and removing the visual indication of the bet from the game interface.

To test this code, I place 1Rs's 3 bet on same spot, then I press the undo button. It will remove whole 3Rs. Bet at a time, but I want to remove bet on a separate time. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There are two overall approaches for undo. 1) keep a list of commands/actions that know how to undo themselves. 2) Save the program state after each action, undo restores a previous state. It is not clear to me how your example is intended to work.

Comment: We would have to know how you **Do** a bet before we can tell you how to **Undo** a bet.

Comment: Doesn't having an Undo button kinda undermine the thrill of the risk of gambling?

Answer (score 2):

As the first comment already says, you can use commands that can undo themselves. The idea is to have a `Command` class having a `Do` and a `Undo` method.
These methods have a `ICommandContext context` parameter (it can in fact be of any useful type, e.g. `Game`). This is basically your game application. It allows the commands to access and act on the game.

```cs
public abstract class Command
{
    public abstract void Do(ICommandContext context);
    public abstract void Undo(ICommandContext context);
}
```

From this abstract class, you derive different commands, e.g., a `PlaceBetCommand`. When `Do` is called, this concrete class must store all the information the `Undo` method needs, to be able to undo the command.

```cs
public class PlaceBetCommand : Command
{
    // Primary constructor
    public PlaceBetCommand(/* TODO: add parameters describing the bet */)
    {
        // TODO: store the parameters
    }

    public override void Do(ICommandContext context)
    {
        // TODO: place the bet and possibly store additional information that you will need in Undo.
    }

    public abstract void Undo(ICommandContext context)
    {
        // Undo the bet
    }
}
```

The reason bet related information is passed as constructor argument(s) is that different commands require different information but the `Do` method has the same parameter for all commands. Alternatively, you could also pass information through properties.

Then you need an undo-stack and possibly a redo-stack (but you didn't ask for a redo functionality).

```cs
private static readonly Stack<Command> _undoStack = new();
```

Placing a bet would go like this

```cs
var bet = new PlaceBetCommand(/* pass the required parameters */);
bet.Do(this);
_undoStack.Push(bet);
```

Undoing goes like this:

```cs
if (_undoStack.Count > 0) {
    var command = _undoStack.Pop();
    command.Undo(this);
}
```

I will let you figure out the details, as I do not know how you place bets and what other commands you might have.

If you want to be able to undo placing 3 Rs's one-by-one, then split it into three commands and execute and push them separately.

---

If you want a redo function, then you need a redo stack of the same type as the undo stack as well.

When you execute a command, you will have to clear the redo stack, because the commands on this stack become invalid (they are valid only immediately after having undone commands).

When you undo a command, place it on the redo stack.

Redoing a command consists of popping a command from the redo stack and then executing its `Do` method and pushing it on the undo stack.